# Find all the words which contain numeric values using regex?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

In my Dot net Application I have to find all the words which contain alphabets and numeric values,I tried to find but fail to find proper answer
I have `(?=.\d)\w+` regex but it returns 45 as valid. Below is my sample list in which bold are right words and other are false words

- **madan45**
- **45madan**
- **mad45an**
- Madan
- 45

I cannot put [a-zA-Z] because my text may contain other than English language ex. โครงการสาวอีสานก็5000บาท.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(?:^|(?<=\s))(?=\S*\d)(?=\S*(?!\s)\D)\S+(?=\s|$)
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/cJ6zQ3/15

Comment: I cannot put [a-zA-Z] because my text may contain other than English language ex. โครงการสาวอีสานก็5000บาท

Comment: @vsk I forgot to check some conditions like(7-8),(14.20),(1,000),(5555+),(50%),("10)"),("10"),([200]) these conditions are incorrect but the above regex extract those also.

Comment: @madan https://regex101.com/r/cJ6zQ3/30 you can add all characters in the character class.I have defined some for you

Answer (score 2):

```
^(?!(\d+|[A-z]+)$)\w+$
```

`(\d+|[A-z]+)$`:all letter or all digit.

`(?!(\d+|[A-z]+)$)`:Negative Lookahead - Assert that it is impossible to match all letter or all digit.

Answer (score 1):

```
(?:\d+[a-z]|[a-z]+\d)[a-z\d]*
```

This Reg Ex should work for your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

> all the words which contain alphabets and numeric values
>
> > fail to find proper answer I have `(?=.\d)\w+`

You were close. The [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) should match *any* word character before the digit to meet the *numeric* condition. And then, in the main pattern, require a letter:

**Regex:**

```
(?=\w*\d)\d*[A-Za-z]\w*
```

<kbd>[regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hZ7jB5/1)</kbd>

1. Lookahead

   - <kbd>`\w*`</kbd> Any word character: `[A-Za-z0-9_]`
   - <kbd>`\d`</kbd> Requires 1 digit.
2. Main pattern

   - <kbd>`\d*`</kbd> Any digits preceding a letter.
   - <kbd>`[A-Za-z]`</kbd> Requires 1 letter.
   - <kbd>`\w*`</kbd> Rest of the word

Answer (score 1):

This also works:

```
string pattern = @"^(?=\D*\d)(?=\d*\D)\w+$";
```

To check:

```
var inputs = new List<string> { "madan45", "45madan", "mad45an", "Madan", "45" };

foreach (var str in inputs)
    Console.WriteLine($"{str} - {Regex.IsMatch(str, pattern)}");
```

output:

```
//  madan45 - True
//  45madan - True
//  mad45an - True
//  Madan - False
//  45 - False
```

Comment: it doesn't match if i pass more than 1 word in a sting